# sheetengine rotating an object slowly brings it closer

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, sheetengine

I've been trying out [sheetengine 1.2.0](http://sheetengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/98942) but when i create an object and rotate it, it seems to slowly drift towards the camera.

I'm using methods seen in the examples and according to the documentation this should be fine.

```
// move object around
            var maxsteps = 10;
            var direction = {x:5, y:0, z:0};
            var rotate = true;
            setInterval(function() 
            {
                lolwut.rotate({x:1, y:0, z: 1}, Math.PI/2/maxsteps);

                // calculate sheets and draw scene
                sheetengine.calc.calculateChangedSheets();
                sheetengine.drawing.drawScene();
            }, 30);
```

There is no current issue on the codeplex page that seems to match what i'm seeing.

Am i doing something wrong?

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XKUvQ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty much seems that the axis you provide has to be normalized. The axis in your example after normalization would look something like this:

```
lolwut.rotate({x:Math.sqrt(2)/2, y:0, z: Math.sqrt(2)/2}, Math.PI/2/maxsteps);
```

I consider this a bug, although the workaround is trivial. I have updated the documentation on codeplex accordingly.